# How to get a test resource file?

Tags: java, testing, resources, maven, surefire

In a unit test I need to import a csv file. This is located in the resources folder, i.e. src/test/resources

Comment: Found simple solution (Java7+) here : https://stackoverflow.com/a/42375654/1579667

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Probably just useful if you have the file available, for example when doing unit tests - this will not load it out of a jar AFAIK.

```
URL url = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("mypackage/YourFile.csv");
File file = new File(url.getPath());
// where the file is in the classpath eg. <project>/src/test/resources/mypackage/YourFile.csv
```

Comment: what I was really looking for was abstraction from providing the path to the file, as in getResourceAsStream. Otherwise new File/getFile is more straightforward

Comment: url is null for me with that statement

Comment: @hithwen ok fixed my answer, the path you specify is actually relative to the classpath, so you should leave out the `src/test/resources` part. (getResource returns null if it can't find the file)

Comment: the resolution of the file ends up including the package of the current class. @hithwen

Comment: Need to use `new File(url.toURI());` to correctly handle spaces in file path.

Answer (score 24):

You can access test resources using the current thread's classloader:

```
InputStream stream = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader()
    .getResourceAsStream("YOURFILE.CSV");
```

Comment: but I want a java.io.File and not an InputStream.

Comment: then use getClass().getResource("/src/test/resources/YourFile.csv"); http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html

Comment: so, FileUtils.toFile(Thread.currentThread().getClass().getResource("/src/test/resources/YourFile.csv"));

Answer (score 14):

with guava

```
import com.google.common.io.Resources;
URL url = Resources.getResource("YourFile.csv");
```

Comment: as @simpatico wants a `java.io.File`, this answer can go on with: `File csvFile = new File( url.toURI() );`

Answer (score 9):

```
// assuming a file src/test/resources/some-file.csv exists:

import java.io.InputStream;
// ...
InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("some-file.csv");
```

Answer (score 4):

```
import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
...
 final File dic = FileUtils.getFile("src","test", "resources", "csvFile");
```

since [Apache Commons IO 2.1](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IO-261).

Answer (score 0):

This solution need not lib's. First create a util class to access the resource files.

```
public class TestUtil(Class classObj, String resourceName) throws IOException{
   URL resourceUrl = classObj.getResource(FileSystems.getDefault().getSeparator()+resourceName);
   assertNotNull(resourceUrl);
   return new File(resourceUrl.getFile());
}
```

Now you just need to call the method with the class of your unitTest and the name of your file in the ressource folder.

```
File cvsTestFile = TestUtil.GetDocFromResource(getClass(), "MyTestFile.cvs");
```

Comment: where can I get FileSystems class ?

Comment: @ToKra java.nio.file.FileSystems